# Static header in fragment navigation drawer

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, header, navigation-drawer

[image]i created an android project in adt with navigation type as navigation drawer as provided in adt. I want to add a static header Edittext widget to the drawer non scroll able and immovable  at the top of listview on navigation drawer in xml list will be scrollable but the header should remain static on its postion all the time, any help will be most appreciated. Do i need to upload the code of xml i thought it would be useless since the question is pretty simple but if anyone want the xml code ask me and i'll upload it.

This is my activity_main.xml

```
<!-- A DrawerLayout is intended to be used as the top-level content view using                    
match_parent for both width and height to consume the full space available. -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout       
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.appname.MainActivity" >

<!--
     As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions.
-->

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!--
     android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
     this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
     languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
     If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
     android:layout_gravity="left" instead.
-->
<!--
     The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
     the container.
-->


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:name="com.example.appname.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is my fragment_navigation_drawer.xml

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#eee"
android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
android:divider="@color/line_divider"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:dividerHeight="1dp"
android:padding="5dp"
tools:context="com.example.appname.NavigationDrawerFragment" />
```

Logcat

```
08-07 10:20:59.274: E/AndroidRuntime(22577):    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-07 10:20:59.274: E/AndroidRuntime(22577):    java.lang.ClassCastException:    android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to    android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams

08-07 10:20:59.274: E/AndroidRuntime(22577):    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.isDrawerView(DrawerLayout.java:910)

08-07 10:20:59.274: E/AndroidRuntime(22577):    at    android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(DrawerLayout.java:1156)

08-07 10:20:59.274: E/AndroidRuntime(22577):    at com.example.appname.NavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:148)

08-07 10:20:59.274: E/AndroidRuntime(22577):    at com.example.appname.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:141)

08-07 10:20:59.274: E/AndroidRuntime(22577):    at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2490)

08-07 10:20:59.274: E/AndroidRuntime(22577):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:224)

08-07 10:20:59.274: E/AndroidRuntime(22577):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:232)

08-07 10:20:59.274: E/AndroidRuntime(22577):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:146)

08-07 10:20:59.274: E/AndroidRuntime(22577):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:199)

08-07 10:20:59.274: E/AndroidRuntime(22577):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:293)

08-07 10:20:59.274: E/AndroidRuntime(22577):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:407)

08-07 10:20:59.274: E/AndroidRuntime(22577):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.doInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:769)

08-07 10:20:59.274: E/AndroidRuntime(22577):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:201)

08-07 10:20:59.274: E/AndroidRuntime(22577):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)

08-07 10:20:59.274: E/AndroidRuntime(22577):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)

08-07 10:20:59.274: E/AndroidRuntime(22577):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

08-07 10:20:59.274: E/AndroidRuntime(22577):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)

08-07 10:20:59.274: E/AndroidRuntime(22577):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

08-07 10:20:59.274: E/AndroidRuntime(22577):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

08-07 10:20:59.274: E/AndroidRuntime(22577):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)

08-07 10:20:59.274: E/AndroidRuntime(22577):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)

08-07 10:20:59.274: E/AndroidRuntime(22577):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: No i'm still facing the same problem

Comment: i have uploaded a picture, this is what my navigation drawer and list look like only difference is that i'm fetching my list data from database, what i want is to add a static EditText as a header, so that when the list is scrolled the EditText remain on its position all the time.

Comment: And why exactly did my answer not help you? Putting an `EditText` at a fixed position above the `ListView` is exactly what my answer does.

Comment: when i put it there it gives an Error for which i have uploaded the logcat details, i have even tried to create a linearLayout and add the EditTest and then the listView in fragment_navigation_drawer.xml. I'm using <fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"......
    android:layout_gravity="start" />, and i must have both EditText and ListView in my DrawerLayout

Comment: Well the error is pretty obvious: `java.lang.ClassCastException:    android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to    android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams`. So you are using the wrong `LayoutParams`! Use `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` instead of `DrawerLayout.LayoutParams`.

Answer (score 0):

The `NavigationDrawer` doesn't have to be a `ListView`, it can be anything. In your case try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flFragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#111">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etHeader"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvDrawer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:layout_below="@id/etHeader"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Xaver K. This is exactly what i need. I have uploaded the xml code now. i have added your changes to my code when i run it app stops "Unfortunately your app has stopped". No Warnings or Errors now

Comment: I need to see the stack trace of the crash. Look at your logcat and edit the relevant error into your question.

Comment: i have uploaded a screenshot of logcat, is it fine to upload the screenshot?

Comment: @mushahid You should copy the text from the logcat and put it in a code block. Screenshots are only supposed to be used for screenshots of an app or something like that, but never to show code or error messages.

Comment: But the error is right there in the logcat: `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams`. So you are using the wrong `LayoutParams` somewhere or you are at least mixing `LayoutParams` up.